# php form data not inserted in mysql database no error comes on the screen?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I make a php form and Insert the form entries into mysql database. php script and form relies on same page. Form also used validation rules. After fill all form entries finally when I hit submit I got no any error but when I checked my database there is no insert entry, what is the problemb? How to solve it? Here is my complete code..

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$regErr = $nameErr = $misErr = $vbErr = $statErr = $tmErr = "";
$reg = $name = $mis = $vb = $stat = $tm = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if (empty($_POST["Reg"]))
     {$regErr = "Reg ID is required";}
     else
     {
     $reg = $_POST["Reg"];
}
   if (empty($_POST["Name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
     else
     {
     $name = $_POST["Name"];

          // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
     {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["Mis"]))
     {$misErr = "Please Enter Marks";}
   else
     {
     $mis = $_POST["Mis"];
     // check if value entered is Numeric
     if(!is_numeric($mis)) {
    $misErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
     }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["Vb"]))
     {$vbErr = "Please Enter Marks";}
   else
     {
     $vb = $_POST["Vb"];
     // check if value entered is Numeric
     if(!is_numeric($vb)) {
    $vbErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
     }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["Stat"]))
     {$statErr = "Please Enter Marks";}
   else
     {
     $stat = $_POST["Stat"];
     // check if value entered is Numeric
     if(!is_numeric($stat)) {
    $statErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
     }
     }

     if (empty($_POST["Tmarks"]))
     {$tmErr = "Please Enter Marks";}
   else
     {
     $tm = $_POST["Tmarks"];
     // check if value entered is Numeric
     if(!is_numeric($tm)) {
    $tmErr = "Data entered was not numeric";
     }
     }     
}
// 1. Creating Database Connection
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    if ($connection) {

print "Database Found";

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found";

}
    if (!$connection){
    die("Database connection failed:".mysql_error());
    }
    // 2. Select a Database to use
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("csresult",$connection);       
    if (!$db_select) {
        die ("Database Selection failed:".mysql_error());
            }

$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO record ('reg', 'name', 'mis', 'vb', 'stat', 'total') VALUES ('".$reg."', '".$name."', '".$mis."', '".$vb."', '".$stat."', '".$tm."')",$connection);
echo $sql;  

echo "1 record added";  

mysql_close($connection);

?>



<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"> 
<table width=600 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2 style='color:white;'>
<tr>
<td>Registration#:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Reg"><span class="error">* <?php echo $regErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Student Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Name"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>MIS Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Mis"><span class="error">*<?php echo $misErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>VB.NET Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Vb"><span class="error">*<?php echo $vbErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stat Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Stat"><span class="error">*<?php echo $statErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Subject Total Marks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Tmarks"><span class="error">*<?php echo $tmErr;?></span></td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<p style='margin-left:300px;'><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: 1- Change your `INSERT` query to `INSERT INTO record (\`reg\`, \`name\`, \`mis\`, \`vb\`, \`stat\`, \`total\`) VALUES ..`, -> change the `'` single quotes to `\`` backticks. 2- use `or die(mysql_error()` -> `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error()` when testing / in doubt to get your error message. 3- `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, update to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. Instead, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO record ('reg', 'name', 'mis', 'vb', 'stat', 'total') VALUES ('$reg', '$name', '$mis', '$vb', '$stat', '$tm')",$connection);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backtick instead of `'` or remove `'` from column names. if you used any reserved words as your column name then you should use `backtick`

Try this,

```
 $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO record (`reg`, `name`, `mis`, `vb`, `stat`, `total`) 
       VALUES ('".$reg."', '".$name."', '".$mis."', '".$vb."', '".$stat."', '".$tm."')") 
      or die(mysql_error());
```

instead of

```
 $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO record ('reg', 'name', 'mis', 'vb', 'stat', 'total') VALUES ('".$reg."', '".$name."', '".$mis."', '".$vb."', '".$stat."', '".$tm."')",$connection);
```

Comment: @ Krish R no any error comes, but after implementing Bill Karwin suggest I got this error "Unknown column '' in 'field list'" . I checked very carefully all fields in database their names i can't find any issue of my declared columns. I don't know where is problem.

Comment: did you implemented my code? i have added the mysql error synatx. and can you post your table structure

Comment: Unknown column 'stat' in 'field list'

Comment: May be in your table column name `stat` has some white space either front or after. Can you rename and check it

Comment: Thanks its working Now .. in my database the name of field state instead of stat.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting single-quotes around your column names. Single-quotes are for string literals and date literals.

```
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO record ('reg', 'name', 'mis', 'vb', 'stat', 'total') ...
```

Should be:

```
$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO record (reg, name, mis, vb, stat, total) ...
```

Some people are suggesting using back-ticks but that's not necessary unless your column names contain SQL reserved words or special characters.

You should always check the return value from mysql_query(), because it returns **false** if there's an error. If this is the case, you have to report the error message yourself.

```
$sql = mysql_query(...);
if ($sql === false) { die(mysql_error()); }
```

Other tips:

- You're writing code using the ext/mysql functions, which are deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO. These functions also return **false** if there's an error.
- You're writing code in an unsafe manner. Before you put any of your code on the internet, please read about SQL injection: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection/) and [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for answering @Bill Karwin .. I used your second suggestion, since I am not familiar with mysqli_ syntax. Now adding mysql_error function I got this error "Database FoundUnknown column '' in 'field list'" . I checked very carefully all fields in database their names i can't find any issue of my declared columns. I don't know where is problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use mysql, use mysqli. Anyways use like

```
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO record (reg, name, mis, vb, stat, total) VALUES ('$reg', '$name', '$mis', '$vb', '$stat', '$tm')";
mysql_query($query_insert,$connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue and found answer by myself. You only need to `<form method="post"` remove this `method="post"` and retype it again. Or also you can change the entire POST methods to GET, it will also work.